# Timeout exception when connecting to MongoLab using c# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mlab

I am using C# driver to connect to MongoDB hosted on MongoLab but I am receiving the Timeout Exception.

Any idea how it can be solved below is my code for the same:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String uri = @"mongodb://test:test@ds011111.mongolab.com:11111/db";

        var client = new MongoClient(uri);

        var db = client.GetDatabase("db");

        Console.WriteLine(client.Cluster.ClusterId.ToString());
        collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

        GetData();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void GetData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting....");

        var res = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved, the error occurred because of network restrictions.